# Pyproj Invalid projection: +init=epsg:25832

Tags: python, pyproj

In my Python Pandas project I have a .csv file with geographic coordinates and want to transform it into lat,lon format.

the last weeks I successfully used the following code to make it work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyproj as pp

def key():
    df = pd.read_csv('POI_Untersuchungsgebiet.csv')

    utm2geo = pp.Proj(init='epsg:25832')
    df[['lon', 'lat']] = df.apply(lambda row: utm2geo(row['x'], row['y'], inverse=True), axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
    key_columns = ['fclass', 'lon', 'lat', 'code', 'Kategorie']
    df = df[key_columns]
    return df
```

Since today I get the following error message

> Invalid projection: +init=epsg:25832 (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: SQLite error on SELECT name, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, geodetic_crs_auth_name, geodetic_crs_code, conversion_auth_name, conversion_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM projected_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name)

Any ideas what the reason could be?

Comment: same error message....

Comment: Same error message reported here https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2020-December/053177.html. The answer was `You're likely 
using a PROJ < 8 library with a proj.db from PROJ 7.2 or 8. Check PROJ_LIB`.

Comment: I'm not using GDAL or OSGeo4W environment.

Comment: see [nternal PROJ Error … SQLite error on SELECT](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#internal-proj-error-sqlite-error-on-select)

Comment: You are still using Proj and the coordinate system database "proj.db". The issue is the same.

Comment: Have you fixed this? @DGIS I have the same error so I upgraded my proj to 8.1.1 but the same error shows. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413943/failed-to-process-srs-definition-error-when-reprojecting-vector-layer-via-ogr2

Comment: @BallpenMan no sorry. I think finally I found a workaround for what I had to do.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your pyproj is referencing an incorrect crs data directory ([see this error in the pyproj doc's](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#internal-proj-error-sqlite-error-on-select)).

This has happened to me when switching kernels in Jupyter notebook/lab or in VSCode and the pyproj data directory remains in the base environment or an environment different from your current environment.

You check your proj data directory:

```
>>> import pyproj
>>> pyproj.datadir.get_data_dir()
'.../opt/anaconda3/envs/test-env/share/proj'
```

But imagine if you were working in a different env, such as `dev-env`. You can see pyproj's data directory is referencing a different env, `test-env`'s proj data directory, causing issues.

You can fix that by specifying the correct path. Below replace `Users/User` with your machine's file path to your anaconda installation and `dev-env` with the current env in use (or remove that part of the path if you are working in your base env):

```
>>> pyproj.datadir.set_data_dir('/opt/anaconda3/dev-env/share/proj')
```

I've also seen this manifest in a similar error: `CRSError: Invalid projection: ESPG:4326: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: crs not found)`.