# Creating geometry from lat/lon column using Python

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, latitude-longitude, pyproj

I used the code:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

geom = gpd.points_from_xy(dat['lon'], dat['lat'], crs=4326)
dat = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=dat[['value']], geometry=geom)
```

but I receive the error:

> CRSError: Invalid projection: epsg:4326: (Internal Proj Error:
> proj_create: SQLite error on SELECT name, type,
> coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name,
> datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition,
> deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such
> column: area_of_use_auth_name)

What is wrong?

The link below is that data I used
[the link for the file used](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H7dwev02hbHmwBcxxj914MDoHyb5jVdu/view?usp=sharing)

Version info:

- `pyproj`: 2.6.1
- `pandas`: 1.4.4
- `geopandas`: 0.12.2
- conda version 22.11.1
  import sys
  import pyproj
  import geopandas
  print(sys.version)
  print(pyproj.**version**)
  print(geopandas.**version**)
  import sys
  import pyproj
  import geopandas
  print(sys.version)
  print(pyproj.**version**)
  print(geopandas.**version**)
  import sys
  import pyproj
  import geopandas
  print(sys.version)
  print(pyproj.**version**)
  print(geopandas.**version**)
  3.9.13 (main, Aug 25 2022, 23:51:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
  2.6.1.post1
  0.12.2
  <pyproj.datadir.get_data_dir()>
  'C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyproj\proj_dir\share\proj'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyproj Invalid projection: +init=epsg:25832](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383883/pyproj-invalid-projection-init-epsg25832)

Comment: i tried what Shawn suggested but it still didint work out. The file is in a netcdf format if it can help provide more information to help me with the problem

Comment: "deprecated FROM" strongly suggests something needs updated

Comment: @Mox  . You can access the link now. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: @Mox link is here, please check

Comment: @JuliusBamah: your file is way too large, please identify a much smaller subset of records that you can ideally directly embed in your post.
Please, also give the version of: `pandas`, `geopandas` and `pyproj` that you are using. You are certainly using a too old `pyproj`. See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383883/pyproj-invalid-projection-init-epsg25832

Comment: @swiss_knight the versions are pyproj: 2.6.1 , pandas 1.4.4 , Geopandas : 0.12.2

Comment: Now give you environment information (OS, Python version, Python path, etc.) and which [`Proj`](https://proj.org/) version is installed and how it was installed. Also please upgrade your packages with: `python -m pip install -U pandas` (same for `geopandas` and `pyproj`). And try your code again after all that. You should always give these information when you first write a question on the Internet otherwise it will be impossible for the other to help.

Comment: @swiss_knight the update worked but i want to create mask from the data. Have tried different codes but aint working. Is there a way you could assist

Answer (score 2):

You are certainly facing this issue: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1887

which is also know by pyproj: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#internal-proj-error-sqlite-error-on-select

> The PROJ database is based on the EPSG database. With each release, there is a good chance that there are database updates. If you have multiple versions of PROJ installed on your systems and the search path for the data directory becomes mixed up, you may see an error message like: SQLite error on SELECT. This is likely due to a version of PROJ attempting to use an incompatible database.

So a [pyproj](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/) / [proj](https://proj.org/) cleaning/update will certainly help, because on a "up-to-date" and "clean" system, everything should work out of the box:

E.g. this example from the [GeoPandas documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html) is not showing the error:

```py
#Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov  2 2022, 18:53:38) [GCC 11.3.0]

import pandas as pd # version: '1.5.2'
import geopandas as gpd # version:  '0.12.2'

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'City': ['Buenos Aires', 'Brasilia', 'Santiago', 'Bogota', 'Caracas'],
     'Country': ['Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Chile', 'Colombia', 'Venezuela'],
     'Latitude': [-34.58, -15.78, -33.45, 4.60, 10.48],
     'Longitude': [-58.66, -47.91, -70.66, -74.08, -66.86]})
df
```

`df` is the following, having a `Latitude` and a `Longitude` column:

```py
           City    Country  Latitude  Longitude
0  Buenos Aires  Argentina    -34.58     -58.66
1      Brasilia     Brazil    -15.78     -47.91
2      Santiago      Chile    -33.45     -70.66
3        Bogota   Colombia      4.60     -74.08
4       Caracas  Venezuela     10.48     -66.86
```

Now you can simply convert this to a [`GeoDataFrame`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html) using the [`points_from_xy`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.points_from_xy.html) method and it should work out of the box. Maybe you want to try using the full [EPSG](https://epsg.org/) string: `EPSG:4326`, or a [`pyproj.CRS`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/crs/crs.html#pyproj.crs.CRS.from_user_input):

```py
import pyproj # version: '3.4.1'

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df,
    geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(
        x = df.Longitude,
        y = df.Latitude,
        crs = 'EPSG:4326', # or: crs = pyproj.CRS.from_user_input(4326)
    )

)

gdf
```

`gdf` looks like, with a brand new `geometry` column:

```py
           City    Country  Latitude  Longitude                     geometry
0  Buenos Aires  Argentina    -34.58     -58.66  POINT (-58.66000 -34.58000)
1      Brasilia     Brazil    -15.78     -47.91  POINT (-47.91000 -15.78000)
2      Santiago      Chile    -33.45     -70.66  POINT (-70.66000 -33.45000)
3        Bogota   Colombia      4.60     -74.08    POINT (-74.08000 4.60000)
4       Caracas  Venezuela     10.48     -66.86   POINT (-66.86000 10.48000)
```

and it has a `crs` assigned:

```py
gdf.crs

>: 
  <Geographic 2D CRS: EPSG:4326>
  Name: WGS 84
  Axis Info [ellipsoidal]:
  - Lat[north]: Geodetic latitude (degree)
  - Lon[east]: Geodetic longitude (degree)
  Area of Use:
  - name: World.
  - bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
  Datum: World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble
  - Ellipsoid: WGS 84
  - Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

See also: [Pyproj Invalid projection: +init=epsg:25832](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383883/pyproj-invalid-projection-init-epsg25832)

Answer (score 1):

Your python environment is likely corrupted and you have multiple versions of PROJ installed on your system.

https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#internal-proj-error-sqlite-error-on-select

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to find a solution to my question using the following: i updated pyproj, geopandas and pandas with `python -m pip install -U pandas (same for geopandas and pyproj)` I proceeded to check the list of the packages in jupyter notebook using `pip list`. Then i restarted the kernel and run the code again.